# Is it possible to put entire object into shared memory? C++

Tags: c++, shared-memory

I would like to a object into shared memory. Say there is a class called Animal

```
    int main()
    {
       int shmid;

       Animal * a;

       shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(Animal), IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL );

       a = (Animal *)shmat(shmid,0,0);

       *a = Animal();
     }
```

And I always get bus error from this approach. Is it possible to put entire object into shared memory? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, use placement `new`.

Comment: that shouldn't fix the problem though. perhaps something wrong with the copy constructor? first of all, do some error handling.. check the return values.

Comment: At least you could add a TI-DSP or MCSDK tag or move the whole thing to TI E2E.....

Comment: @user3528438: huh? :) how did you manage to post that here?

Comment: It depends on the object.  If it is entirely composed of basic types, it should be possible.  If it uses containers, strings or the like, then you'll need custom allocators, which also use shared memory.

Comment: @JamesKanze: good catch, that would explain the bus error.

Comment: "And I always get bus error from this approach." - you mean the consumer app is crashing, a not this code snippet, right?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: It's quite possible that `*a =`  causes `operator=` to crash with a bus error. If the assignment operator tries to clean up the old contents, but the object wasn't initialized, bad things are expected.